# Rmi server like in j2ee

Tags: jakarta-ee, rmi

Good morning.
I'm currently using a daemon written in java, and it has a RMI object that accept connections from a graphical client.
it's very simple, and RMI is not very good in scalability.
Now i want to move to web application for have customer interactions with the server via web browser, but i have a doubt.
Is there a way to run a daemon in a application server, and accepting client interactions via http?
the problem is that a part of the daemon must run continuosly (in my rmi server i have a separate thread), for doing file processing, and cannot be invoked only on client's requests.

Comment: You could do the same thing with web services. For example you could create a REST web service and call it from the client.

Comment: can't do in this way. a thread of the application must run continuosly.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't continue to use your RMI server, and expose the interface via a Web Service? "Using Spring’s support for RMI, you can transparently expose your services through the RMI infrastructure. " http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

Comment: REST Service will be answer here

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Java EE 7. You can implement the continuously running running daemon with a @StartUp EJB and a ManagedExecutorService.

Comment: ...or even use the batch processing facility.